# @angular/cli npm install error

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I get the following error while I am trying to run `npm install @angular/cli`.

I have tried changing proxy port no but it does not work.

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT XXX.XX.X.100:8080
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!
```

Comment: Do you use a proxy?

Comment: Yes, corporate proxy

Comment: Well, than you have it in the message.